# Computing memory usage of the process including its children

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a way to programmatically get memory usage of a process and its children on Linux.

I tried reading RSS from `/proc/{pid}/stat`:

```
1 (systemd) S 0 1 1 0 -1 4194560 21462 218671 205 576 23 96 127 356 20 0 1 0 15 21913600 3286 18446744073709551615 1 1 0 0 0 0 671173123 4096 1260 0 0 0 17 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Here 24th field is 3286 which is the number of pages in real memory. I could multiply this by `getpagesize()` to get memory usage in bytes, then do the same for all child processes recursively and sum the results.

However, doing so overcounts shared memory between processes, and doesn't include swapped pages, which is not ideal.

I thought about parsing `/proc/{pid}/mem` and somehow identifying shared memory ranges, but this sounds way to slow for realtime memory usage sampling.

Is there a faster/easier way to get memory usage of a process? I don't mind if it only counts pages and not individual allocations.

Note that I'm not looking for a shell-script based solution, since spawning a shell process every second is not an option, especially if the system is overloaded by thousands of processes - shell won't get enough cpu time to compute the result.